# Replace values in file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a files:

```
$cat file1.txt
1234|W
1345|S
8427|D
2132|C
3243|V
```

and my sql file is :

```
$cat select.sql
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE ID IN (FLAG);
```

and I have a shell with the next instructions

```
$cat replace.ksh
!#/bin/ksh

S_ids=`awk -F"|" '{print "\47" $1 "\47" ","}' file1.txt |sed '$s/,$//'`

sed -i "s/FLAG/${S_ids}/g" select.sql
```

I required put the values of the varible "S_ids" in the file `select.sql` input of word FLAG
the result must by:

```
$cat select.sql
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE ID IN ('1234',
'1345',
'8427',
'2132',
'3243');
```

I have tried `sed -i "s/FLAG/${S_ids}/g" select.sql` but didn't get expected result.

Comment: is $i an exported variable that's set to "file1.txt"? Otherwise, I don't see it being set in `replace.ksh`.

Comment: $i is file1.txt

Comment: Reality check please: your database field `CUSTOMERS.ID` really is a string rather than an integer?

Comment: Hello!!, The field CUSTOMER.ID is varchar could contains letters.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work can be inferred from the error message (that you omitted to provide):

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
```

The `sed` command does not accept a multi-line value. You have to collapse your multiple lines into a single line. You could do this with a script such as this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
S_ids="'$(cut -d'|' -f1 file1.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/ *$//' -e "s/ /','/g")'"
sed -i "s/FLAG/${S_ids}/g" select.sql
```

To see how `S_ids` is generated you can take each piece of the pipeline

```
cut -d'|' -f1 file.txt        # Extract first column
tr '\n' ' '                   # Convert newlines to spaces
sed -e 's/ *$//'              # Strip the trailing space
sed -e "s/ /','/g"            # Replace each remaining space with the three characters ','
```

Answer (score 0):

```ksh
#! /bin/ksh

inputfile='file1.txt'
sqlfile='select.sql'

S_ids=$(awk -F"|" '{gsub(/^|$/,"\\'\''",$1) ; print $1","}' "$inputfile" | 
        xargs | 
        sed -e 's/,$//')

sed -i "s/FLAG/${S_ids}/g" "$sqlfile"
```

Output:

```
$ cat select.sql 
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE ID IN ('1234', '1345', '8427', '2132', '3243');
```

This uses `awk`'s `gsub()` function to add `\'` at the start and `\',` at the end of the first field of each line.  It adds `\'` rather than just `'` so that the single-quote survives the pipe through `xargs`.

Note the use of `'\''` to embed a single-quote inside the single-quoted `awk` script - read that as "end-single-quote, escaped-single-quote, start-single-quote-again".

`xargs` with no command to run defaults to `xargs echo` so that puts all of the output lines (single quoted first fields of file1.txt) onto one line, separated by spaces.  This will work unless there are many tens of thousands of lines in `file1.txt` - enough to exceed the maximum shell line length (typically 128KB or more).

Finally, it pipes the output of `xargs` into `sed` to strip the final `,` from the line.

If you prefer to have newlines after each ID in `select.sql`, change the last line of the script to:

```
sed -i "s/FLAG/${S_ids}/g; s/, /\n/g" "$sqlfile"
```

Output will be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE ID IN ('1234',
'1345',
'8427',
'2132',
'3243');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ FLAG=$(awk -F\| '{printf("%s, ", $1)}' file1.txt)
$ echo $FLAG 
1234, 1345, 8427, 2132, 3243,
$ sed "s/FLAG/${FLAG%%, }/" select.sql
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE ID IN (1234, 1345, 8427, 2132, 3243);
```

This depends on the flag list being small enough to fit on the command line.  If it's not, you can use **getline** in awk to process file1.txt, gathering the replacement string in a `BEGIN` pattern, and then process select.sql.